Multi Robot Navigation Using ROS2 Humble
I am currently trying to set up multi robot navigation in a custom world that I made on gazebo using two turtlebot3(waffle). However, in spite of using the exact same code as provided on the NAV2 github, the project is not working properly.The only changes I made to this code was changing the world, map name and param files(with the corresponding map name on there). The code I am using is exactly the same as mentioned here, but the navigation stack does not start up properly. However, both of the robots spawn at the correct location. I have attached the logs I see below. Any help on this would be appreciated.
The ROS distro I am using is Humble
PS: Such similar code worked on ROS2 Iron a year ago. Right now, we are trying to replicate our old code with some changes we made to the world.
[gazebo-1] [Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call

[lifecycle_manager-7] [INFO] [1731355144.836541097] [robot1.lifecycle_manager_slam]: Destroying lifecycle_manager_slam
[lifecycle_manager-14] [INFO] [1731355144.836755740] [robot2.lifecycle_manager_slam]: Destroying lifecycle_manager_slam
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.841469201] [robot2.behavior_server]: Destroying bond (behavior_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.841530352] [robot2.planner_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (planner_server)
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.841563389] [robot2.planner_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.865596615] [robot2.global_costmap.global_costmap]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.868398003] [robot2.planner_server]: Cleaning up plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.868506314] [robot2.planner_server]: Destroying plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.874545610] [robot2.planner_server]: Destroying bond (planner_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.874567924] [robot2.smoother_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (smoother_server)
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.874582878] [robot2.smoother_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.879528549] [robot2.smoother_server]: Destroying bond (smoother_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.879550676] [robot2.lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Running Nav2 LifecycleManager rcl preshutdown (lifecycle_manager_navigation)
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.885928511] [robot2.controller_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (controller_server)
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.885963065] [robot2.controller_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.886302497] [robot2.local_costmap.local_costmap]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-12] [INFO] [1731355144.896708910] [robot2.controller_server]: Destroying bond (controller_server) to lifecycle manager.
[map_saver_server-13] [INFO] [1731355144.843109088] [robot2.map_saver]: Cleaning up
[map_saver_server-13] [INFO] [1731355144.843170841] [robot2.map_saver]: Destroying bond (map_saver) to lifecycle manager.
[map_saver_server-13] [INFO] [1731355144.846231727] [robot2.map_saver]: Destroying
[map_saver_server-6] [INFO] [1731355144.843659315] [robot1.map_saver]: Cleaning up
[map_saver_server-6] [INFO] [1731355144.843698311] [robot1.map_saver]: Destroying bond (map_saver) to lifecycle manager.
[map_saver_server-6] [INFO] [1731355144.846391846] [robot1.map_saver]: Destroying
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871804963] [robot1.waypoint_follower]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (waypoint_follower)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871857056] [robot1.waypoint_follower]: Destroying bond (waypoint_follower) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871862776] [robot1.bt_navigator]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (bt_navigator)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871869658] [robot1.bt_navigator]: Destroying bond (bt_navigator) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871874285] [robot1.behavior_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (behavior_server)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.871893398] [robot1.behavior_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.874463992] [robot1.behavior_server]: Destroying bond (behavior_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.874488489] [robot1.planner_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (planner_server)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.874506190] [robot1.planner_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.880910349] [robot1.global_costmap.global_costmap]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.883366215] [robot1.planner_server]: Cleaning up plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.883463393] [robot1.planner_server]: Destroying plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.888917586] [robot1.planner_server]: Destroying bond (planner_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.888936922] [robot1.smoother_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (smoother_server)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.888951437] [robot1.smoother_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894016270] [robot1.smoother_server]: Destroying bond (smoother_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894042486] [robot1.velocity_smoother]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (velocity_smoother)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894052239] [robot1.velocity_smoother]: Destroying bond (velocity_smoother) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894075825] [robot1.controller_server]: Running Nav2 LifecycleNode rcl preshutdown (controller_server)
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894098274] [robot1.controller_server]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.894512393] [robot1.local_costmap.local_costmap]: Cleaning up
[component_container_isolated-5] [INFO] [1731355144.905369690] [robot1.controller_server]: Destroying bond (controller_server) to lifecycle manager.
